# Py4j Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: py4j/GatewayServer

Tags: java, python, py4j

I want python to call java method using py4j, when I packaged the java file as jar, and run in windows, it went wrong:

```
>java -jar spark-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: py4j/GatewayServer
    at com.littlely.AddNum.main(AddNum.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: py4j.GatewayServer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

the java:

```
package com.littlely;
import py4j.GatewayServer;

public class AddNum{
    public float add(float a, float b){
        return a + b;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GatewayServer server = new GatewayServer(new AddNum());
        server.start();
        System.out.println("server started!");
}}
```

the python:

```
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway

def main():
    jvm = JavaGateway().jvm
    myadd = jvm.com.littlely.AddNum()
    print(myadd.add(40.0, 80.0))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have add the main-class to the manifest.MF file, what is wrong with it? How can I deal with it, and I'm new to java, please give me an example.